# How to register new user with curl using djoser?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am new to djoser and while following a tutorial, I tried to register a new user using the command :

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ --data 'username=example%26password=mysecret'
```

(I am using `%26` in the url because `&` is giving errors.)

But unfortunately I am getting the output as :

```
{"username":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}
```

Instead of:

```
{"email":"","username":"example","id":1}
```

My **urls.py** file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^api/', include('djoser.urls'))
]
```

My **settings.py** file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',

    ]
}
```

I am executing this as:

In one terminal, I am running sqlite server, and in another terminal, I run the above command.

I have a doubt whether it's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

curl should be

```
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/?username=example&password=mysecret'
```